# How to play video one after one in jsp array

Tags: html, arrays, jsp, video

I would like to play video sequentially in a folder names "video" by using array method. However i can only play the first video.Is that anyway i can change the video src after finishing the 1st video so i can play it one after one.Thanks.

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> 

<html>
<body>
    <% 
    String DIRECTORY_VIDEO = "video";
    String FolderOriginal = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + DIRECTORY_VIDEO;
    File dir = new File(FolderOriginal);
    String[] files = dir.list();    
    int videolength = files.length;
    String newdirectory = DIRECTORY_VIDEO+"/";
    %>
       <video id="myVideo" height="100%" width="100%" controls autoplay">   
         <source id="ss" src="<%=newdirectory+files[0]%>" type='video/mp4'>
       </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by adding a callback to the video and loading a new video src ?

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/1v9oauru/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#myVideo").bind("ended",function(){
    $("#myVideo source").attr("src","http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
    $("#myVideo")[0].load();
    $("#myVideo")[0].play();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

For Video events refer the below link
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#mediaevents

Comment: still how i gonna put my array files inside $("#myVideo source").attr("src","http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");.because i have more than just 2 video files .thanks

Comment: @user3686208 convert your list of video files to a `javascript` array. Use a `javascript` global counter, in the bind function get the url from the `javascript` array using the counter as index.